# IEnumerable from DBContext vs IEnumerable from code Memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm getting confused with IEnumerable memory usage problem, especially compare IEnumerable data source from DB and IEnumerable data source from code `yield return` const values.

I have a `Memory` function for checking the memory usage.

```
        static string Memory()
        {
            return (Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 
                    1024)).ToString();
        }
```

1. So here I'm using EF CORE 3.0, accessing a total of 150000 records table

```
            using DataContext context = new DataContext();

            Console.WriteLine(Memory()); //21

            IEnumerable<User> users = context.Users;
            foreach (var i in users) {}

            Console.WriteLine(Memory());//101
            Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalMemory(true));//46620032
```

for some reason I cannot upload pics, so I need to type the results sorry about that.(results are in the code as comments).

2. And the next example is using `yield return` to generate the IEnumerable data.

```
        static IEnumerable<User> Generator(int max)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                yield return new User { Id = 1, Name = "test" };
            }
        }
```

here is the result

```
            Console.WriteLine(Memory());// 21

            IEnumerable<User> users = Generator(150000);
            foreach (var i in users){}

            Console.WriteLine(Memory());// 24
            Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalMemory(true)); // 658040
```

Now, I'm very confused by example 1 and 2. My understanding is that for IEnumerable data source, it's going to read one at the time, rather than the whole collection, so it can reduce the memory usage just like the example 2. However, when it comes to using EF CORE(I know this not specific to EF CORE, but I need a concrete example for that.), I think it's still pulling one by one, but my question is why it uses so much more memory than the second example. So is it pulling each record one by one? And at the end, I have all the records from DB in memory is it correct? But why the second use so less memory? I'm yielding the same records. If some could explain this is much appreciated. Thanks !!!

Comment: EF Core does not pull records one by one and actually it returns `IQueryable` not `IEnumerable`

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius when I iterate the collection it has to be `IEnumerable ` cannot be `IQueryable `. And it's pulling one by one as both `iqueryable` and `ienumerable` are deferred execution.

Comment: `IQueryable` _extends_ `IEnumerable`, so anything you do on an `IEnumerable` you can also do on an `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed EF (Core) specific behavior called (change) tracking, explained in [Tracking vs. No-Tracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking). Note that tracking is the default behavior if you don't change it explicitly

```
context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

or use `AsNoTracking()` on the query source.

The essential is that even though the query result is evaluated one by one, the `DbContext` instance adds each created entity instance plus some additional info like state and snapshot of the original values into some internal list. So even without key, status and original values snapshot, the equivalent code for the generator would be something like this:

```
IEnumerable<User> users = Generator(150000);
var trackedUsers = new List<User>();
foreach (var i in users)
{
    trackedUsers.Add(i);
}
```

So at the end of the loop you would have all created instances during iteration stored in memory.

That's why you might consider using `AsNoTracking` option in case all you need it to execute an entity query and iterate it once. Note that non entity (projection) queries and keyless entities do not track their results, so this is really entity query specific behavior.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer to my question, I will give it a try soon to prove it.

Comment: I've added `AsNoTracking` and the memory drops dramatically, but still not the same as `yield return`, maybe this is because of something ef core internal?(it's still doing something that can not be optimised)

Comment: and also I just want to double-check that, ef is pulling records one by one right? rather than loading the whole collection all at once. even I do `var users = context.Users.ToList();` there will be one sql query and pulling one by one, and then save the records in memory, is it correct?

Comment: The result of query execution is ADO.NET data reader, which then is iterated one by one and materialized into objects. See [How Query Works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works). `var users = context.Users.ToList();` is just a shortcut for `var users = new List<User>(); foreach (var user in context.Users) users.Add(user);`, so yes, it's one query and then creating and saving the objects in memory.

Comment: oh, so even it's no-tracking query ef still has some checks and tracks the results, so that's maybe the reason why the memory usage is still a little higher than `yield return` ? what do you reckon?

Comment: The last depends of the EF Core version. - in 3.0 the local tracking of no-tracking query [has been removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#no-tracking-queries-no-longer-perform-identity-resolution) because of the *"additional performance and memory overhead"* it was adding. So if you are testing with 1.x / 2.x, you probably see that memory overhead.

Comment: ah, I see, that makes a lot of sense to me. Sorry just final one last thing I want to ask that is as far as I know, when I ask data from EF it always gives me IEnumerable data source. I can not get the whole collection all at once which may cause some serious problems when consuming big data set. right? As DbSet Implements IEnumerable so it always gives me records one by one. There is no easy way to get the whole collection as a whole.

Comment: hopefully I understand this correctly, thank you very much for your time and knowledge.

Comment: You can *easily* get the whole collection by executing the query represented by the db set w/o any filter and buffer the results into let say list (`ToList()`). Behind the scenes it will still get the data in chunks from the database server, because this is how data readers (database cursors) work. The data has to be transferred somehow from database to the client and converted to objects by the ORM layer, and then it can easily be cached (stored in some in-memory collection) or just iterated and processed one-by-one...

Comment: … Both scenarios are easily supported by `IEnumerable<T>` and `ToList` / `ToArray` and similar helper methods. Anyway, glad being helpful, cheers.

Comment: thanks again for your help, you are amazing. do you mind if I can follow your social media like Twitter or something similar?

Comment: He-he, I'm afraid SO is the only sort of a "social" place I'm in. But thanks for asking, and you are welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

In you code, once you execute the foreach statement, EF goes to the database and fetch **all** the records to memory and enumerates the results. It is the same as:

```
var list = context.Users.ToList();
foreach (user u in list)
{
}
```

Without knowing how the User class is defined it is hard to tell why the memory consumption is the way it is (and I'm not saying it's too high), but once you get entities in EF, there is a lot going on behind the scenes, like change tracking, that consume memory.

and BTW, IQueryable is IEnumerable

```
public interface IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IQueryable
```

Answer (score -1):

> My understanding is that for IEnumerable data source, it's going to read one at the time, rather than the whole collection, so it can reduce the memory usage just like the example 2.

This is not true for Linq-to-Entities. It will run a query to get *all* data, and just allow you to iterate over it once it's loaded.

There *may* be some optimizations as far as paging, etc. that could happen by some providers, but in general EF does not pull records "one-by-one" from the database.  The data will be stored in the context, which adds memory overhead.  If you dispose of the context after you're done with it (which is a best practice), you might see a dramatic decrease in memory.

> But why the second use so less memory?

Because in the loop, you create an object, return it, then do nothing else with it. So each object is eligible for garbage collection very quickly, and thus total memory used will be less. Plus you don't have the overhead of the `DbContext` (which shouldn't be huge)

Note that garbage collection is *not* deterministic. It's possible that, given the right circumstances, that nothing would be collected, and you'd see much more memory used by the second loop.